# How do i create a foreign key on table creation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a automatic table creation with a foreign key connected so that i can show the data in the same table. How should i make the connection between the tables as they are created.

Note: The tables are created at the same time. with the `Palle_tbs` first in the load order.

I dont know if Alter Table can be used in this example, since the tables are created at the same time. if so how should i do it?

i've tried to make a reference to the other table like so.

`addcsv.php` This is where i call the methods.
`$lastest_filename` is not getting used atm.

```
$csv->createPalleTable($latest_filename);
$csv->insertPalleTable($latest_filename, array_map("toNumber", fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")));

$csv->createHoejde1($latest_filename);
$csv->insertHoejde1Table($latest_filename, array_map("toNumber", fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")));
```

I can add more code, just think it would make it more confusing.

`Csv.php` This is where i make the tables and the inserts.

**EDIT i have updated my attempt**

I expect the tables to be connected. the results i've gotten was `FK_palle = 0`

```
public function createHoejde1($latest_filename){
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csvHoejde1`( 
        id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(50), 
        Datum VARCHAR(50), 
        Property VARCHAR(50), 
        Criterion VARCHAR(50),
        Type VARCHAR(50), 
        Nominal DECIMAL(10,2),    
        Actual DECIMAL(10,2),     
        Tolminus DECIMAL(10,2),   
        Tolplus DECIMAL(10,2),    
        Dev DECIMAL(10,2),
        FK_palle INT(11) REFERENCES Palle_tbs(`id`))
      ");}

public function insertHoejde1Table($latest_filename ,$getdata){
    return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `csvHoejde1` (`Name`, `Datum`, `Property`, `Criterion`, `Type`, `Nominal`, `Actual`,`Tolminus`,`Tolplus`,`Dev`)
    VALUES (:Name, :Datum, :Property, :Criterion, :Type, :Nominal, :Actual, :Tolminus, :Tolplus, :Dev)",
        [
        ':Name' => $getdata[0],
        ':Datum'=> $getdata[1],
        ':Property'=> $getdata[2],
        ':Criterion'=> $getdata[3],
        ':Type'=> $getdata[4],
        ':Nominal'=> $getdata[5], 
        ':Actual'=> $getdata[6],  
        ':Tolminus'=> $getdata[7],
        ':Tolplus'=> $getdata[8], 
        ':Dev'=> $getdata[9]      
        ]
    );}

public function createPalleTable($latest_filename){
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Palle_tbs`(
        id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Palle_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Varenummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Ordre_nummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Operatoer VARCHAR(50), 
        Maskine_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Raavare_batch_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Dato_ur_stillet VARCHAR(50), 
        Klokke_fuldsvejst VARCHAR(50), 
        Fuldstoebning_af_klokke VARCHAR(50),
        Afgratning_af_overflade VARCHAR(50), 
        Vaegt DECIMAL(10,2))
      ");}

public function insertPalleTable($latest_filename ,$palledata){
    return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `Palle_tbs` (`Palle_nr`, `Varenummer`, `Ordre_nummer`, `Operatoer`, `Maskine_nr`,
     `Raavare_batch_nr`, `Dato_ur_stillet`,`Klokke_fuldsvejst`,`Fuldstoebning_af_klokke`,`Afgratning_af_overflade`,`Vaegt`)
    VALUES (:Palle_nr, :Varenummer, :Ordre_nummer, :Operatoer, :Maskine_nr, :Raavare_batch_nr, :Dato_ur_stillet,
     :Klokke_fuldsvejst, :Fuldstoebning_af_klokke, :Afgratning_af_overflade, :Vaegt)",
        [

        ':Palle_nr' => $palledata[0],
        ':Varenummer'=> $palledata[1],
        ':Ordre_nummer'=> $palledata[2],
        ':Operatoer'=> $palledata[3],
        ':Maskine_nr'=> $palledata[4],
        ':Raavare_batch_nr'=> $palledata[5],
        ':Dato_ur_stillet'=> $palledata[6],
        ':Klokke_fuldsvejst'=> $palledata[7],
        ':Fuldstoebning_af_klokke'=> $palledata[8],
        ':Afgratning_af_overflade'=> $palledata[9],
        ':Vaegt'=> $palledata[10]
        ]
    );}
```

result is on FK_palle is 0

Comment: The referenced table must exists when you attempt to create the foreign key.

Comment: That makes sense. ill try create the table first then try use the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference `table1` into `table2`, you need first to create `table1`

In your statement, you wrote `FOREIGN KEY (FK_product) REFERENCES product_tb(product_id)`. There is no `product_id` field in `product_tb` table, you meant to reference the primary key `id`

Then, you can use the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

In example :

```
CREATE TABLE table1
( --         ^----^-----------------------------------+
    id INT(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, -- |
--  ^^---------------------------------------------------+
    someData VARCHAR(255)                          -- |  |
);                                                 -- |  |
                                                   -- |  |
CREATE TABLE table2                                -- |  |
(                                                  -- |  |
    id INT(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, -- |  |
    otherData VARCHAR(255), --                        |  |
    table1_id INT(6), --               +--------------+  |
 -- ^-------^-------+                  |      +----------+
    --              |                  |      |
    --          v-------v            v----v  vv
    FOREIGN KEY table1_id REFERENCES table1 (id)
);
```

Then, you can use `INSERT` queries to fill the tables. For table2, you'll have to insert the foreign key, it won't be done automatically (your DB doesn't know which row is referenced)

In example :

```
INSERT INTO table1
--         id
--         |    someData
--         |       |
--      v-----v  v---v
VALUES (DEFAULT, "foo"),
       (DEFAULT, "bar");

INSERT INTO table2
--         id
--         |    otherData
--         |        |          table1_id
--         |        |              |
--      v-----v  v------v          v
VALUES (DEFAULT, "blabla",         1),
       (DEFAULT, "bob the sponge", 1),
       (DEFAULT, "John Smith",     1),
       (DEFAULT, "forty two",      2),
       (DEFAULT, "Hello world",    2);
```

Comment: I really think it makes sense but it just wont work. can you tell me what i have done wrong? The table Palle_tbs does already exist if needed

Comment: it gives me a 0 as result

Comment: This is a `CREATE TABLE` statement, not a `SELECT`. You shouldn't get results. Did you checked in your favorite DB management tool (phpMyAdmin / MySQL Workbench) if the table was created succesfully?

Comment: it doesnt make any relations to the other tabel. (using phpMyAdmin), what i mean with result still being 0 is that it doesnt connect to an id. so when data is inserted into the table it says 0 and not the id number of the `palle_tbs.id`

Comment: did you included the foreign key in your insert query?

Comment: Thanks the foreign key connection works now! just need to figure out how to get it to insert the data from the id

Comment: [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) can help you